# document with maximum appearance in a collection mongodb

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a mongo database of this structure:

```
 people:{
    {
     'code': '234',
     'name': 'x'
    },
    {
     'code': '432',
     'name': 'y'
    },
    {
     'code': '234',
     'name': 'x'
    }
 }
```

The result of my query should be:

```
{
  'code': '234',
  'name': 'x'
}
```

I would like to retrieve this value as it has maximum occurrence in this collection. I'm trying with aggregate and count methods, but couldn't properly manage it.

What would be the command to do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pipeline:

```
pipeline = [
    {'$group': {'_id': '$code', 'count': {'$sum': 1}}},
    {'$sort': {'count': -1}}
]
```

It will sort documents by number of occurrences in descending order. Example:

```
In [4]: pymongo.MongoClient().whatever.test.aggregate(pipeline)
Out[4]: {'result': [{'_id': 234.0, 'count': 2}, {'_id': 432.0, 'count': 1}], 'ok': 1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Mongo Shell:-**

```
>>>db.people.aggregate([
        {$group:{_id:{code:"$code",name:"$name"},count:{$sum:1}}},
        {$sort:{count:-1}},
        {$limit:1}
    ])


{ "_id" : { "code" : "234", "name" : "x" }, "count" : 2 }
```